# How to determine position of single slit minima?

Tags: optics, visible-light, interference, superposition

[image: Diagram]
[image: Text]

Why does path difference between waves from two secondary sources equal half a wavelength?

And why is $\sin(\theta) = \frac\lambda b$?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

see the second diagram. and there you have the relation.

Answer (score 0):

The path difference is half a wavelength only fot the first minima fringes, for the next minima we should have path differences of an integer multiple of half a wavelength.